# Getting error installing updates (in Canada)

Tags: update-manager

I am trying to install updates for a Dell XPS running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It fails with the following error:

> Failed to download package files
>
> Check your Internet connection.

Details

> Failed to fetch [http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa-lts-quantal/libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-quantal_9.0.2-0ubuntu0.1~precise1_amd64.deb](http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa-lts-quantal/libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-quantal_9.0.2-0ubuntu0.1%7Eprecise1_amd64.deb) 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
> Failed to fetch [http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa-lts-quantal/libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal_9.0.2-0ubuntu0.1~precise1_amd64.deb](http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa-lts-quantal/libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal_9.0.2-0ubuntu0.1%7Eprecise1_amd64.deb) 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
> Failed to fetch [http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa-lts-quantal/libglapi-mesa-lts-quantal_9.0.2-0ubuntu0.1~precise1_amd64.deb](http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa-lts-quantal/libglapi-mesa-lts-quantal_9.0.2-0ubuntu0.1%7Eprecise1_amd64.deb) 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
> Failed to fetch [http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa-lts-quantal/libxatracker1-lts-quantal_9.0.2-0ubuntu0.1~precise1_amd64.deb](http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa-lts-quantal/libxatracker1-lts-quantal_9.0.2-0ubuntu0.1%7Eprecise1_amd64.deb) 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
> Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nautilus/libnautilus-extension1a_3.4.2-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
> ...

At the time of this posting, these files are not on the server. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server is down you could go into software sources and choose another server.
See the "download from". You now have it set to Canada. If you change it too a US server and it does download your server is probably down.

[image]

Comment: The server is up, but it's a 404 error. I guess the ca server's not reliable. Anyway, I switched it as you said and it worked.